# How can I count all rows that there are in a table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I searched in google and I found the following command:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name
```

And I used the above code as follows to count all rows that there are in a table.

```
$number = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($number);
echo $rows;
```

But when I see the result using the `echo` command, I see the result as the `1` value. While number of rows in my table is `12`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query just returns 1 row. That row **contains** the count of rows in it. You need to fetch the row to get the answer, just like you do to get the results from any other query.

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table_name");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$rows = $row['count'];
echo $rows;
```